Why is the switch not returning the information from a different method?
I am trying to change my coding so that the switch function can be placed in a different method but be used by the first method.
Here is the code for context:
 static void Main(string[] args)
 { 

     int FP = 20;

     int CHA = 8;
     int STR = 8;
     int AGI = 8;
     int PERC = 8;
     int END = 8;
     int HP = AGI * 3;

     int thug = 10;
     int TD = 2;

     while (FP > 0)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Your Current Stats: " + "\nCHA: " + CHA + "\nSTR: " + STR + "\nAGI: " + AGI + "\nPERC: " + PERC + "\nEND: " + END + "\nHP: " + HP);


         Console.WriteLine("You have  " + FP + " free points left.");
         Console.WriteLine("");
         Console.WriteLine("Allows for adding up to in 1, 5, and 10's. Add the number after the stat. Examples: CHA1, CHA5 CHA10");
         Console.WriteLine("");
         Console.WriteLine("Where would you like to apply your Free Points: |CHA|:Charisma, |STR| Strength, |AGI|:Aglility, |PERC|:Perception, |END|:Endurance");
         string points = Console.ReadLine();
         points = points.ToUpper();


         switch (points)
         {
             case "CHA1":
                 CHA++;
                 FP--;
                 break;
             case "CHA5":
                 CHA = CHA + 5;
                 FP = FP - 5;
                 break;
             case "CHA10":
                 CHA = CHA + 10;
                 FP = FP - 10;
                 break;

             case "STR1":
                 STR++;
                 FP--;
                 break;
             case "STR5":
                 STR = STR + 5;
                 FP = FP - 5;
                 break;
             case "STR10":
                 STR = STR + 10;
                 FP = FP - 10;
                 break;

             case "AGI1":
                 AGI++;
                 FP--;
                 break;
             case "AGI5":
                 AGI = AGI + 5;
                 FP = FP - 5;
                 break;
             case "AG10":
                 AGI = AGI + 10;
                 FP = FP - 10;
                 break;

             case "PERC1":
                 PERC++;
                 FP--;
                 break;
             case "PERC5":
                 PERC = PERC + 5;
                 FP = FP - 5;
                 break;
             case "PERC10":
                 PERC = PERC + 10;
                 FP = FP - 10;
                 break;

             case "END1":
                 END++;
                 HP = HP + 8;
                 FP--;
                 break;
             case "END5":
                 END = END + 5;
                 HP = HP + 40;
                 FP = FP - 5;
                 break;
             case "END10":
                 END = END + 10;
                 HP = HP + 80;
                 FP = FP - 10;
                 break;
             default:
                 Console.WriteLine("That is not a stat.");
             break;

         }

     }

What I put down was this:
static string response(int CHA, int STR, int AGI, int PERC, int END, int HP, int FP, string points)

{

    while (FP > 0)
    {
        switch (points)
        {
            case "CHA1":
                CHA++;
                FP--;
                break;
            case "CHA5":
                CHA = CHA + 5;
                FP = FP - 5;
                break;
            case "CHA10":
                CHA = CHA + 10;
                FP = FP - 10;
                break;

            case "STR1":
                STR++;
                FP--;
                break;
            case "STR5":
                STR = STR + 5;
                FP = FP - 5;
                break;
            case "STR10":
                STR = STR + 10;
                FP = FP - 10;
                break;

            case "AGI1":
                AGI++;
                FP--;
                break;
            case "AGI5":
                AGI = AGI + 5;
                FP = FP - 5;
                break;
            case "AG10":
                AGI = AGI + 10;
                FP = FP - 10;
                break;

            case "PERC1":
                PERC++;
                FP--;
                break;
            case "PERC5":
                PERC = PERC + 5;
                FP = FP - 5;
                break;
            case "PERC10":
                PERC = PERC + 10;
                FP = FP - 10;
                break;

            case "END1":
                END++;
                HP = HP + 8;
                FP--;
                break;
            case "END5":
                END = END + 5;
                HP = HP + 40;
                FP = FP - 5;
                break;
            case "END10":
                END = END + 10;
                HP = HP + 80;
                FP = FP - 10;
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a stat.");
                break;



        }
    }
    return points;
}


Make sure you're calling the new function response from Main

In your Main method, you're allowing user input to change the value of points on every iteration. In response you're not. And all you're returning from response is the same points string that you passed in. Changing the values of the passed-in parameters in C# does not change the values from the calling function unless you use something like ref parameters.

Your switch statement is already repetitive and complicated, and it's only going to get worse. What do you plan to do if the user uses 19 of their FP and then chooses "END10"? Are you okay with them ending with -9 FP? Consider organizing your code according to the concepts that you're trying to envision: parse the inputs into values that represent a stat key/value pair, so you can validate the value in one place. Consider representing the stats as a Dictionary, so most of your code is just a matter of looking up the key and adding to its value, with a small tweak to add HP for END.
